# Что значит и для чего используется запись вида Button b = (Button) sender;?

Tags: c#

Тут мне практически нечего добавить к вопросу из заголовка. Приведу лишь пример того, где мне это встретилось. В данном случае эта функция написана для обработки нажатий на "числовые кнопки" калькулятора, т.е. 1, 2, 3 и т.д.

```
    void b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = (Button)sender;
        tb.Text += b.Text;
    }
```

Comment: это приведение типа с присвоением, оно необходимо, чтобы Вы в коде далее могли обратиться к методу класса `Button`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как уже сказали в комментариях - это приведение к типу. Если Вы обратите внимание на тип параметра `sender`, то сможете увидеть, что типом является `object`. Для доступа же к свойству `Text`, необходимо тип `object` привести к типу `Button`.
Помимо этого, Вы можете приводить `sender` к базовому типу. Как Вы можете видеть из иерархии наследования [класса Button](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.button?view=netframework-4.8) он наследуется от [класса Control](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control?view=netframework-4.8), к которому Вы можете приводить и `button` и множество других элементов.

---

#### Ссылки по теме

- [Приведение и преобразование типов](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions)
- [Обзор обработчиков событий (Windows Forms)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/event-handlers-overview-windows-forms)
- [Класс Button](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.button?view=netframework-4.8)
- [Класс Control](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control?view=netframework-4.8)